# ASP.NET MVC dependency injectable partial view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, viewmodel, ninject, partial-views

I want to display some data from HttpContext.Current.Cache via a partial view _CacheData.cshtml in my ASP.NET MVC _Layout.cshtml page. I wrote a wrapper ICacheManager so I can inject it into my controllers. ICacheManager also has its own dependency on IFooRepository

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{
    public CacheManager(IFooRepository repo, System.Web.Caching.Cache cache)
    { ... }
}
```

I'm using Ninject.MVC3 nuget package so here is my RegisterServices

```
private static void(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IFooRepository>().To<FooRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<ICacheManager>().To<CacheManager>().WithConstructorArgument("cache", x => HttpContext.Current.Cache);
}
```

This works great for my controllers, but how can I inject a `CacheManager` into a partial view? There's no controller for _CacheData.cshtml. I can get a `CacheManager` in a base controller and put it in ViewBag, but that doesn't feel right. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a child controller action, where you put the data from cache into a view model and render your partial view with `Html.Action()`.

Comment: this is pretty much what I ended up doing, seemed to work ok. Can you explain the difference between a controller and a child controller? i don't see a difference other than you can put [ChildActionOnly] on your actions

Comment: No difference, you can put child action on any controller. I usually create a MasterController for child actions I use in a master/layout page.